# Is there any way to avoid using exit(0)?

Tags: c, recursion

I wanted to practice a little with separating logic into functions and using basic recursion in a primitive "Guess my number game", just as a sort of way to see where I'm at in my C programming.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

char playAgain()
{
    printf("\nDo you wanna play again? ");
    char resp = 0;
    while (TRUE) {
        scanf("%c", &resp);
        if (resp == 'y') break;
        if (resp == 'n') break;
    }
    return resp;
}

void play()
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int num = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int guess = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int attempts = 0;

    printf("\nGuess the number: \n");
    while (TRUE) {
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if (num > guess)
        {
            printf("Too low! ");
            attempts++;
        }
        else if (num < guess)
        {
            printf("Too high! ");
            attempts++;
        }
        else if (num == guess)
        {
            attempts++;
            printf("You won! You did it in %d attempts", attempts);
            char yo = playAgain();
            if (yo == 'y') play();
            else if (yo == 'n') exit(0);
            else {
                printf("Error!");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    return play();
}
```

Everything works but I've only managed to make it quit when the user says 'n', by using exit(0) and I've heard it's bad practice. But having spent a couple of hours just noodling around and trying all the other ways I could think of (using flags, for example), I just couldn't make it work. It works for 'y', but as soon as I enter 'n', it doesn't quit and just calls the playAgain() function one more time, or freezes altogether (nothing happens).

I feel ashamed for not being able to solve this, but I'm out of ideas. Is there any other way, other than exit(0), to make it jump out of play() straight to return 0 in main()? The problem seems to be that I have an infinite game loop, so when the answer is 'n', I need to break out of the loop AND out of the play() function, and that has proven to be problematic. I remember being able to do this easily when I had no functions, but just all the relevant code in main(), but the whole point of this is to use functions. For example, I can't figure out how to make use of a return type of play(), so that it knows when to quit.

P.S. As always, seeing how often people get accused of this, I assure you this is not homework because I am, and always have been, doing programming strictly as a hobby. There's no professor I answer to, apart from you :-) And trust me that I did try to figure out a solution, but nothing seems to work. It's a question of good vs. bad design, so it's especially important for my self-teaching. exit(0) seems to be a hackish solution and serves no educational purpose.

P.P.S. By the way, I'm using xCode, and the program runs in its output window. Probably not, but maybe that's the reason quitting with 'n' doesn't work?

SUMMARY: The code works fine except when the answer is 'n', in which case it just asks "Do you wanna play?" again, or doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c", &resp);`  (Add space)

Comment: Changed it, 'n' still doesn't work. 'y' does.

Comment: in general, try not to change the original code you post, it makes everyones answers look odd since the question effectively changes :)

Comment: You never change your variable `flag`.

Comment: Yes, I apologise for editing the code. The flag variable shouldn't have been there at all. I've reverted it back to original (using exit(0)).

Comment: Maybe `if (yo == 'y') { play(); return 0;}`.

Comment: But then return 0 will never get called, will it? Since play() is a function, and it just goes over and over again, without ever reaching return 0.

Comment: Good point, then `else if (yo == 'n') return  0;` also.  Sorry if I.m not on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your play function return a result:-  `int play( void ) {`

then instead of `exit(1)` and `exit(0);` use `return 1;` and `return 0;`

at the end of play put `return 0;`

then in main

```
{
return play();
}
```

instead of recursion,  just make a loop

```
int play( void)
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int num;
    int guess;
    int flag;

    while(1)
    {
        num = rand() % 10 + 1;
        guess = 0;
        flag = 0;
        printf("\nGuess the number %d: \n", num);
        while (1) {
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            if (num > guess)
            {
                printf("Too low! ");
            }
            else if (num < guess)
            {
                printf("Too high! ");
            }
            else if (num == guess)
            {
                printf("You won!");
                char yo = playAgain();
                if (yo == 'y') break;
                else if (yo == 'n') return 0;
                else {
                    printf("Error!");
                    return  1;
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

and if you want more of a game engine type approach

```
enum {  
    GUESS,
    GAMEOVER,
    QUIT,

} GAME_STATES;

typedef struct 
{
    enum GAME_STATES state;
    int num;    
    int game_over;
} guessing_game_t;


void init_game(guessing_game_t* g)
{   
    g->state = GUESS;
    g->game_over = 0;
    g->num = rand() % 10 + 1;
}

void evaluate_guess(guessing_game_t* g, int guess)
{
    if(g->num == guess)
    {
        printf("You won!");
        g->state = GAMEOVER;
    }
    else if (g->num > guess)
    {
        printf("Too low! ");
    }
    else if (g->num < guess)
    {
        printf("Too high! ");
    }
}

int input_guess( void )
{
    int guess;
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    return guess;
}

void play_again( guessing_game_t* g)
{   
    char resp = 0;

    printf("\nDo you wanna play again? ");
    scanf("%c", &resp);
    if (resp == 'y') init_game(g);
    if (resp == 'n') g->state = QUIT;

}

void play( guessing_game_t* g)
{
    while(g->state != QUIT)
    {
        switch(g->state)
        {
        case GUESS:
            evaluate_guess(g, input_guess());
            break;
        case GAMEOVER:
            play_again(g);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    guessing_game_t game;
    init_game(&game);
    play(&game);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and I tried doing that, but it doesn't work when it's 'n'. It just freezes. Maybe there's a bug somewhere else. I've edited the code to show that.

Comment: just changed it to show how to get rid of the recursion

Comment: Recursion is NEVER the right answer for anything that can easily be solved with a simple loop. I really wish folks would emphasize that when teaching it; it seems to have become a common disease... or at least the instructor who is teaching this badly has an unusually large percentage of students here on StackOverflow.

Comment: not quite true, I wish in C, they'd leave out recursion,  and then in whatever functional language they want, they teach recursion.

Comment: I didn't HAVE to use recursion here, no one told me to, I just wanted to try it. That's all. This isn't from any book or tutorial. This is just me fooling around :) As I said, I can easily solve this without using functions at all, let alone recursion, but that was the whole point for me. Maybe it just doesn't make sense here.

Comment: I've updated it with a game engine type approach which avoids some of the problems and is also really extensible to handle all kinds of different game states

Comment: since you are self learning, I thought you'd might be interested to see that approach as it is the approach a lot of games tend to take

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Once again, thank you. Didn't expect to get such a response, but it's much more valuable than what I was asking initially. I do want to eventually get into game development.  And your code is also a great applied showcase to some "proto-OOP" features of C, using structs and enums that way. In essence, that was my idea with trying to separate such a simple game into functions. I'd never done that before.  Will keep on learning now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a flag before going on with the loop
Change the while(true) to while (continue_play), continue_play is the name of flag for an example

Then,

```
if (yo == 'n') exit(0);
```

can be change to

```
if (yo == 'n') continue_play=false;
```

and do the similar for the exit(1) case

continue_play then will be a flag to exit from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you may recursive call you `play()` function, I think exit it with `exit(0)` is a proper choose.

Acutall, I do not think using recursion to implement `play()` is a good idea at all, two infinite loops are enough. You could implemet it like this:

```
void play(void)
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int num;
    int guess = 0;
    int attempts = 0;
    int try_again = 1;

    while (try_again) {
        num = rand() % 10 + 1;
        printf("\nGuess the number: \n");
        while (TRUE) {
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            if (num > guess)
            {
                printf("Too low! ");
                attempts++;
            }
            else if (num < guess)
            {
                printf("Too high! ");
                attempts++;
            }
            else if (num == guess)
            {
                attempts++;
                printf("You won! You did it in %d attempts", attempts);
                char yo = playAgain();
                if (yo == 'n') try_again = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one more thing that the program will end: the logic of your code is made like that u can also use `break;` instead of `exit(0)` and `exit(1)` because you use while loop and you will break it and the program will end.